# How to pre-empt git pull merge error?

Tags: git

I am looking for a way of detecting up front whether a `git pull` or `git merge` would fail. The sort of script I want to perform is to update a server.

```
git fetch
git okay
stop server
backup data
git merge
start server
```

Here `git okay` is a place holder for the command I am asking for.

If a file has been changed outside of a commit then `git pull` fails with the following error.

```
error: Your local changes to '...' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

I would like `git okay` to perform the pre-merge checks described in `git merge` and return non-zero status so that the script aborts before the server is stopped.

Possibilities I have looked for and not found include `git merge --dry-run`. My best line of thought is `git status --porcelain | pre-merge-okay`. That seems like a lot of work to make a `pre-merge-okay` that deals with things like benign untracked files.

Comment: Could you phrase your question in terms of how you want the working directory and index to behave?  It sounds like maybe you're running live out of your working directory, and the running server is permitted to change files in the working directory, and you're looking for a way to test whether the merge will be  automatically resolved without disturbing any files in the working directory (although I don't know if you care about the index changing).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using stash to save your work, and then just *do* the merge, knowing that you can later back it out?  I haven't tried these exact commands, but something like...

```
    git tag remember-your-initial-position
    git stash save --all --include-untracked
    git merge
    if [$? -ne 0]; then
      echo "merge will fail"
      git merge --abort
    else
      git stash apply
      if [$? -ne 0]; then
        echo "reapplying changes after the merge will fail"
      else
        echo "merge will be ok"
      fi
      git reset --hard remember-your-initial-position
    fi
    git stash pop
    git tag -d remember-your-initial-position
```

If there's a reason you don't want to make changes in the working directory (for example, you're actively running your server out of that directory), you could try copying the repo somewhere else and doing these steps elsewhere, like this:

```
    pushd .
    cp -r . /tmp/copy
    cd /tmp/copy
    # do the above steps
    popd
    rm -r /tmp/copy
```

Comment: That would work to push through the deploy while enabling rollback. It is not quite what I am looking for. I would like to abort the deploy early and manually fix any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be an elegant way of doing exactly what I asked for, so I will go with a simple solution. This does mean that I need to clean up untracked files. Some will be removed, others added into .gitignore.

```
test -z "$(git status --porcelain)"
```

Comment: You're generally better off not having a dirty workspace when you merge, so it's great that you're fixing that problem.  One possibly non-obvious catch with what you're doing is that if the .gitignore file is checked in and it changes, then your approach may fail because you have a file that's currently ignored, but the next change will stop ignoring it and it may cause your merge to fail.  In general, the only safe way to be absolutely sure that your merge will work is to actually *do* the merge, and doing it somewhere else (as I suggested in the second part of my answer) is often trivial.